# How do I load Neo4j data from hadoop data by Neo4j brower?

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I want to load the Neo4j data from the Hadoop by the neo4j browser. 
It means that I will try to connect the Hadoop by hive query to use the JDBC driver. 
Then directly create node into the Neo4j. 
I already succeed to load the data from Oracle. But I try to load the data from the Hadoop but I failed.

```
Call apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:ccmedia_dba/ccmedia@ip:port:name",'select REG_NO, NM  from aaa ') YIELD row 
CREATE (n:Re {name:row.NM,num:row.REG_NO});
```

I download the hive JDBC but Neo4j cannot start where I copy the JDBC jar file into the Plugin directory.

I want to know exactly it is possible or not. If possible then please let me know the way.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check the Neo4j logs for errors. Neo4j logs the error in `neo4j.log` file. Check what's the error logged in the log file when you try to start Neo4j and share here.

Comment: Did you check the APOC doc for Hive https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_support_for_hive_with_kerberos_auth